# how to validate radio button without javascript?

Tags: html, validation

I have used radio button for gender as follow:-

```
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked required="required"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other</td>
```

but this "required" validation is not working how to put validation on it without using JavaScript.

Comment: @Fred Because there is no need for any validation here. It's a radio button so all that is needed to achieve what is required is to set one of the options as the default and then all happens without any need for PHP or anything else. Less is more.

Comment: @Fred-ii i want to make same validation as we are put on text field for make sure that it is selected, if you know it then mention here.

Comment: @SmitSaraiya as Amir Kaftan has pointed out to you there is not need for any validation. Just set one of the radio buttons to checked as the default and then one of the radio buttons must be set from that point on. This is very basic HTML behaviour. Pause and think a bit and you'll see you are confusing yourself and others by seeking validation that is meaningless.

Comment: @Fred But it is meaningless to validate a Radio Button group once you have set a default value. No matter how much the OP wants to do something meaningless using PHP or sprinkling it with unicorn urine or anything else it remains meaningless. Doing something meaningless is always a bad idea and a waste of developer and system time. But yes, if it was not a radio button group then I completely agree with you on the PHP way to do this. But it is a radio button group so ... :)

Comment: Ok Smit, I have obviously wasted everyone's time here including my own. I will delete all my comments now. Edit: all deleted. Re-edit: @jwpfox I've deleted all my comments. I feel I have not contributed to resolving their question, obviously.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I think you did good work and made the conversation much more interesting. Hope you didn't get the impression that because we were opting for a simple approach we didn't value your more interesting one (I certainly didn't). There are many paths to glory and just because I am appalling lazy and ready to grab at the $5 answer does't mean I don;t admire those who put in the work to come up with the much more interesting answers that are often more widely applicable and teach everyone more about what is possible.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have to put validation on one textfield, here required validation not mandatory but if user enter value in that text field then it must be 12digit how to set such validation

Comment: are you asking me "how" to do this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i dont want to put required but if user enter any value then it must be 12 digit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Required is a HTML5 attribute for input control validation, you can add the required attribute at end of  tag and if you want Gender radio button checked by default, you can add checked.

This would checked the radio button default when page loads,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked required/> Male
```

This will work, so we no need to go for JS validation.

Answer (score 5):

You can set default value to radio button like this :

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked" />
```

then you have not need to validation...

Answer (score 1):

The required attribute is an HTML5 attribute and if you're using an older browser it may not support it.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp

Also, you simply put "required", not "required="required"", just like with "checked"

Comment: *"Also, you simply put "required", not "required="required""* - Untrue and is valid/suggested syntax https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html

Comment: I was going by the example on the w3schools website.

Comment: If you like them so much, have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp I.e.: *In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the required attribute must be defined as `<input required="required" />`*. See, valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this reference and try it yourself

http://www.chennaisunday.com/jsradio.html